Homebrew an item that increases save DC of Monk ki/focus features on D&DBeyond?
Some items improve monk features. For example, the Dragonhide Belt grants

a bonus to the saving throw DCs of your ki features

Is there a way to create an item that reflects this bonus mechanically on D&D Beyond?

No
There is currently no way to do that in DnDBeyond. The mentioned Dragonhide Belt does not affect DC in your character sheet either, as listed in Support Thread for FIZBAN’S TREASURY OF DRAGONS

Ya, I was hoping that that thread was outdated.
